# ffprobe - How to omit stream disposition info from output?

Tags: ffmpeg

**ffprobe** - For a given audio file, I want to get stream info (specifically, sample rate, duration, bit rate, channel count) and all metadata tags (e.g. id3), ***but nothing else***. After quite a bit of research, I have come up with the following ffprobe command:

```bsh
ffprobe -v error -show_streams -show_format -select_streams a:0 \
        -show_entries "stream=codec_name,bit_rate,channels,sample_rate :
                       format=duration" \
        -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 Song.mp3
```

With this command, you can see in the show_entries arg value, I'm only including codec_name, bit_rate, channels, and sample_rate.

However, the output (see below) includes this unwanted DISPOSITION=xyz crap that I did not ask for in my "show_entries" argument. ***What set of options/args will exclude this DISPOSITION=xyz stuff from my output ?***

I have read through the [ffprobe documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe-all.html#Main-options), but it is not very easy to understand, and couldn't find what I wanted.

***NOTE - I'm aware that I can pipe this command output to grep -v, but that is not an option for me, since I will be running this command as a child process from within my app, and need this to be efficient - grep means starting another process ... not an option.***

In other words, I need to do this with ***ffprobe and ffprobe only***.

```
codec_name=vorbis
sample_rate=44100
channels=2
bit_rate=240000
DISPOSITION:default=0       // DON'T WANT THIS :(
DISPOSITION:dub=0           // DON'T WANT THIS :(
...
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0       // DON'T WANT THIS :(
TAG:ALBUM=Healing Music for Reiki 1
TAG:ARTIST=Aeoliah
TAG:DATE=1995
TAG:FMPS_PLAYCOUNT=1
TAG:FMPS_RATING_AMAROK_SCORE=0.235
TAG:GENRE=New Age
TAG:TITLE=Souls In Ecstacy
TAG:track=2
duration=1682.506667
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have `-show_streams` in there. Also, to show tags, you don't need `-show_format`.

Use

```
./ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0
 -show_entries "stream=codec_name,bit_rate,channels,sample_rate : format=duration : format_tags : stream_tags"
 -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 Song.mp3
```

Comment: Yes Sir ! That's exactly it ... worked like a charm ! Thanks again :) I did read the ffmpeg docs but didn't understand what they meant by "format tags" or "stream tags".

Comment: BTW, I noticed that format_tags doesn't always give me the tags. In some files, stream_tags has the tags I'm looking for. So, to get all tags, it's best to include both format_tags and stream_tags, right ? If you agree, could you please edit your answer ? Or should I edit your answer ? Thanks.